# How to create a report subscription in SSRS which passes today's date to paramters?

Tags: ssrs-2016

I created a report with a StartDate and EndDate parameter. If I want to see the information for a single day, I use the same Date in both parameters. I now want to create a subscription for this report so that it runs everyday. How can I use the current date and pass it to these parameters when the report runs? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This will only work with Enterprise edition.

First, write a query that gets the current date and formats it to match the VALUE in your parameter (for example, is it DD-MM-YYYY, YYYY-MM-DD?). Make sure to name your column something meaningful like "CurrentDate".

```
select cast(current_timestamp as date) as CurrentDate
```

Then create a new subscription for your report. Instead of Standard Subscription, choose data driven subscription. Now select your SQL datasource and paste in your query. Press validate to make sure it runs fine. Hit OK.

Now you can go down to your subscription parameters at the very bottom of the page. Set Source of Value to be "Get value from dataset" then pick your "CurrentDate" from the drop down.

That's it, data driven subscription with current date.

Comment: No Luck, no pun intended :-> I guess I don't have the enterprise version so I don't have the data driven subscription option. Can you think of another way? I just want to run the report once a day and use the current date to input into the query. Thanks!

Comment: also on your stored proc or query side you need 2 date or datetime params. And you will set them in where clause as so... where your_Date_column between @Date_1 and .@Date_2 (keep in mind how date and datetime datatypes behave). You can run the report anytime then and those params will be set to today's date.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: You will have your defaultDates dataset as so. can be query or you can wrap it as a Stored proc.

```
Select TodaysDate = cast(getdate() as date)
```

Step 2: then , under default values for both the params you will anchor get value from dataset and point to this dataset, which is defaultDates.

Step 3: test it locally. Make sure to delete .DATA from your working directory to enforce fresh data.

Step 4: build and deploy to whatever test location.